# Should I have og:description and meta description together on every page?

Tags: seo, meta-description, open-graph-protocol

Or will Google not like it if I have two kinds of description tags?

I just put up a new blog and it automatically adds the `og:description` and `og:title` and I am not sure if that is going to get me penalized or my pages somehow discounted if I have meta description and `og:description` on the same page.

Would anyone know how to best handle this situation? Should I try to get rid of the `og:description`?

The site I am working on is a WordPress site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Short Answer:* Use both!

*Long Answer:*

The OG stands for [Open Graph](http://ogp.me/) which is apart of the Open Graph protocol of which works on platforms such as Facebook.

The [meta description](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?hl=en#1) element is for search engines such as Google, Yahoo and Bing.

Since these are two separate tags that kinda do the same thing but they are designed for different types of platforms, one for Facebook and the other for Search Engines. The reasoning behind this is that the Open Graph protocal is more rich in what content can be feed to Facebook without scrapping the full page, think rich snippets. So images, description and more information is feed to Facebook via the Open Graph.

Using both is a good idea.

Comment: yes to which phrasing of the question? :) Yes it will hurt things? Or yes it is ok? :)

Comment: I reword now :P...